# How to move ImageView from one FlowPane to another FlowPane with animation

Tags: java, animation, javafx

I am trying to move an ImageView from a FlowPane in the bottom to a FlowPane in the middle of my scene. I would like to move it to its natural position. Basically the position it would have if I removed it from the first pane and then added it to the second pane without any animations. I know I could do it by setting x and y coordinates that are about in the middle but that seems not right.

In very simple it would look like this in the end.

flowPaneBottom.remove(imageView1)

Animation here (just straight line)

flowPaneMiddle.add(imageView1)

flowPaneRight.remove(imageView2)

Do Animation again

flowPaneMiddle.add(imageView2)

Comment: If you make a node not visible (i.e. call `setVisible(false)`), it will still occupy space in its parent (it will still be *managed*). So you can try this: 1. Add a *new* image view, with the same image, to the target flow pane, with `setVisible(false)` called on that new image view. 2. Get the coordinates in the scene of the original image view and the new image view. The difference between them will be the amount to translate the original image view. 3. Use a `TranslateTransition` for the original image view. 4. When the animation finishes, remove the original and make the new visible.

Comment: seems like a good solution. thank you

Comment: how can I get the coordinates of the new image?

Comment: something like `image.localToScene(image.getBoundsInLocal())` (which should give you the bounds relative to the scene). You may need to ensure the new image is laid out prior to that (which might be a little tricky); if that's an issue consider implementing a `Transition` directly (because the new image will be positioned by the time `interpolate()` is invoked.